# How do I query for fields that have AT LEAST a given range?

Tags: sqlite

Say I have a table of the form:

```
+-----+-------+
| Key | Value |
+-----+-------+
| A   |     1 |
| A   |     3 |
| A   |     4 |
| B   |     2 |
| B   |     3 |
| C   |     3 |
| C   |     4 |
| C   |     5 |
+-----+-------+
```

I want to be able to return all of the keys that have *at least* a given range.

For example:

A query for a Value range of 2 would return A, B, C
A query for a Value range of 3 would return A, C
A query for a Value range of 4 would return A

Can this be done with SQL (specifically SQLite)? If so, how?

Comment: What if the value has gaps? Is a range of 4 a contiguous series of 4 values? Or just the difference between `MIN` and `MAX` for that key?

Comment: It's the difference between MIN and MAX for that key. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find those with a "range" of at least 4 for example

```
SELECT "Key"
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY "Key"
HAVING (1 + MAX("Value") - MIN ("Value")) >= 4;
```

Obviously alter the `4` as appropriate for the other cases.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d1f1f/4)